# Delete Discord.js v13 slash command that doesnt exist

Tags: javascript, discord.js

lately, I started working on a discord bot and added slash commands.

I noticed that I have a ping(replies with pong) command that I didn't create or I did and I can't get rid of it.

Here is my interactionHandler.js

```js
const { REST } = require("@discordjs/rest");
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");

module.exports = async (err, files, client) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  client.interactionsArray = [];
  files.forEach((file) => {
    const interaction = require(`./../interactions/${file}`);
    client.interactions.set(interaction.data.name, interaction);
    client.interactionsArray.push(interaction.data.toJSON());
  });

  const rest = new REST({ version: "9" }).setToken(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
  
  (async () => {
    try {
      // console.log("Refreshing slash command list");
      // const guildIds = await client.guilds.cache.map((guild) => guild.id);
      // const clientId = await client.user.id;
      // guildIds.forEach(async (guildId) => {
      //   await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
      //     body: client.interactionsArray,
      //   });
      // });
      await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands("934895917453168653", "967384688069066852"),
            { body: client.interactionsArray},
        );

      console.log("Successfully refreshed slash command list");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  })();
};
```

Is there a way to delete the command because I cant find a way.
I was thinking of getting the ID of the command but I don't know how.
Thanks for all the helpers :)
Discord.js v13

Comment: Running that file should delete it, keep in mind that if you are doing it globally (as it shows in your code) it will take time before it updates. Keep in mind that `Routes.applicationGuildCommands()` should only include the clientId not a guildId

Comment: @Gh0st `Routes.applicationGuildCommands()` should contain the guildId and clientId because then how would the API know what guild you want to register commands for?

Comment: You are right just saw it said Routes.applicationGuildCommands rather than Routes.applicationCommands. My first comment I just copied and pasted and  misread that. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands may not be refreshing because of 2 reasons:

- These commands may be **global** commands to change that to refreshing global (instead of guild) commands replace `Routes.applicationGuildCommands` to `Routes.applicationCommands`
- These commands may be from a different guild which in the case you should change the guild ID

To figure out the problem you should do [`client.application.commands.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ApplicationCommandManager?scrollTo=fetch) to get all your commands and then `console.log()` the result.

### Example

```js
//This will fetch all your slash commands
const commands = await client.application.commands.fetch();
//Returns a collection of application commands
console.log(commands);
```